# HttpWebRequest returned with a stale resource even though cache-control has max-stale 0

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest

Given a `HttpWebRequest` performs a GET against a URL with `Cache-Control max-stale=0` and the  server returned a resource with `max-age=900`, why would the returned `HttpWebResponse` have `IsFromCache=true` along with a warning header that the response is stale?

The response stream contains a payload taken from the client's `Temporary Internet Files` when the server side has a newer version of the resource available. It's been more than 900 seconds since the local cache was populated.

I've also observed the result of this to be ambiguous. The same code executing twice will sometimes return the stale resource and sometimes return the updated resource. When returning the updated resource, it doesn't appear to update the `Temporary Internet Files` cache.

Comment: Eh... you as programmer decide what to do with the received data; `HttpWebRequest` is far too low level to use Windows' Temporary Internet Files cache . More likely, there's some router or something in between that does caching with more lenient settings.

Comment: @Nyerguds I've read that .NET uses the same caching as IE via WinInet. For example: http://blog.technovert.com/2013/01/httpclient-caching/. Plus you can see cached entries from HttpWebRequest in 'Temporary Internet Files'. Finally, I've frequently observed caching problems like this be worked around by clearing the cache via IE.

Comment: The article says that said caching is disabled by default on `HTTPWebRequests`, though.